# How to fetch the data from a Json file when it has a number as the name of the structure in swift?

Tags: json, swift, api

**How to fetch the data from this kinda of Json file when it has 0 as the name of the structure ?**

*Since the nature of Swift or any programming languages I might know do not allow the developer using the number as the structure name.*

The location that I wanted to get the data from:

```
*0.confirmed
```

Json code:

```
  [ { "country": "Cambodia", "code": "KH", "confirmed": 198,
     "recovered": 142, "critical": 1, "deaths": 0, "latitude": 12.565679,
     "longitude": 104.990963, "lastChange": "2020-07-23T06:18:34+02:00",
    "lastUpdate": "2020-07-23T16:30:03+02:00" } ]
```

my swift structure:

```
struct CoronaVirusData: codable {
    var Countries: 0
}

struct 0:  codable{
    var critical: Int
    var confirmed: Int
    var deaths:Int
    var recovered:Int
    var lastUpdate: String
```

Comment: I was using Json Viewer Awesome to view the location of the data that I wanna get and it has shown as a 0.confirmed. 

That makes me kinda confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to name that `struct` as 0? You are simply trying to decode an array, not an element named `0`.

Give a meaningful name to your `struct` and simply pass the array type to `JSONDecoder.decode`.

```
struct CoronaVirusData: Codable {
    let critical: Int
    let confirmed: Int
    let deaths: Int
    let recovered: Int
    let lastUpdate: String
}

// Test code
let json = """
[ { "country": "Cambodia", "code": "KH", "confirmed": 198,
   "recovered": 142, "critical": 1, "deaths": 0, "latitude": 12.565679,
   "longitude": 104.990963, "lastChange": "2020-07-23T06:18:34+02:00",
  "lastUpdate": "2020-07-23T16:30:03+02:00" } ]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([CoronaVirusData].self, from: json)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Aren't we supposed the name of structure the same as the structure that have declared in Json format? 


I tried to declared the structure as yours and here is the error. 

`error block 2: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: @vatanachhorn no, the name of your types have nothing to do with how your JSON look like. The property names are what should match the JSON keys - but even that's not necessary as long as you declare a `CodingKey` conforming `enum`.

Comment: @vatanachhorn check my updated answer with the fixed code

Comment: Thank you so much brother. I’ll dig into it by tomorrow. 

Kinda understanding, but not very clear.